# ZFS on linux: switch partition to whole disk

Tags: linux, disk-space, storage, zfs

There is a ZFS pool with raidz1 in it. The pool is created on top of three 2TB drives using the whole disk and a 2TB partition on a 3TB drive.

What is the recommended process to reconfigure the pool to use the whole 3TB disk instead of the partition?

I read a lot the zfs manual (man zpool) but I'm not sure which commands should be used: attach/detach or online/offline and the pool shold be exported or not.

Because the the array is almost full of data, I don't like the idea to just stab in the dark and play with it.

Also, I ran zpool scrub multiple times and it finished without errors.

Comment: You wouldn’t be able to utilize the space either way. In RAID arrays, the smallest member determines the usable array size. This is true even for software RAID.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I know. Later I can replace the 2TB disks too, but that is a simple task.

Comment: I see. Well, the procedure isn’t that complex, I’ll write an answer later. You are aware, however, that this will result in a resilver, right?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem. Actually it is not that hard. Here are the steps:

1. Do a complete scrub on the pool `zpool scrub POOL`
2. Make the disk partition offline with `zpool offline POOL PARTITIN`
3. Check the status with `zpool status POOL`, it should be in a degraded but working status.
4. Here is the tricky part. You have to make zpool to forget that that partition ever was in that pool. I simply used dd to overwrite a few Mb-s on beginning of the disk, like this: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=DISK bs=1M count=10`
5. The last step is to use the replace command like this: `zpool replace POOL OLD-PARTITION NEW-WHOLE-DISK`
6. The previous step will initiate a resilvering of course. After that was finished I made another scrub just to be sure :)

Answer (score -1):

Just run zpool replace POOL OLD-PARTITION NEW-WHOLE-DISK. There is no need to put your array in a jeopardy by removing (logically or physically) a device.

Now even Microsoft Storage Spaces dropping the idea of intentionally endangering the data, putting array into a degraded state.